# ASP.NET CheckListBox 508 Compliance

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, section508

I have a CheckListBox and specify the ToolTip on the items.  When rendered, it shows a span around the checkbox (and label) and it's the span that has he title attribute on it, not the checkbox (input type=checkbox).

Does anyone know how to set the title attribute on the input element instead of the surrounding span?

In order to be 508 compliant, I need to have the title attribute on the input element, not on the span.

**Edit**: Note that I would prefer to do all the necessary changes in C# on the server side.  I would prefer not to have to do it in javascript/jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have tested before I posted. The quickest way is to use old fashioned html controls with the attribute runat="server". You can then reference your individual checkboxes by their IDs. For example:

```
<asp:Panel ID="BrowserCheckBoxList" runat="server">
    <ul>
        <li><input id="CheckBoxList1_0" type="checkbox" name="" value="Chrome" title="Chrome" runat="server" /> <label for="CheckBoxList1_0">Chrome</label></li>
        <li><input id="CheckBoxList1_1" type="checkbox" name="" value="FireFox" title="FireFox" runat="server" /> <label for="CheckBoxList1_1">FireFox</label></li>
        <li><input id="CheckBoxList1_2" type="checkbox" name="" value="IE" title="IE" runat="server" /> <label for="CheckBoxList1_2">IE</label></li>
        <li><input id="CheckBoxList1_3" type="checkbox" name="" value="Opera" title="Opera" runat="server" /><label for="CheckBoxList1_3">Opera</label></li>
        <li><input id="CheckBoxList1_4" type="checkbox" name="" value="Safari" title="Safari" runat="server" /><label for="CheckBoxList1_4">Safari</label></li>
    </ul>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Actually went so far as to contact Microsoft. Based on the funky way they implemented it, there is NO WAY to access the input element of the individual checkboxes within a CheckBoxList.  They recommended using either a GridView with TemplateField of CheckBoxes or Repeater with CheckBoxes and InputAttributes on the checkbox to set the title attribute.

Comment: It depends on what you're building, but GridView may add more overhead to your viewstate than the Repeater control. Assuming you're submitting data to a codebehind rather than a web service or something, you'll have to do more work in your codebehind to obtain values from the controls on submission.

Answer (score 1):

Been there. JavaScript wouldn't help you with 508 anyway since it doesn't change the source code.

This should fix it for you:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreRender(e);
    foreach(ListItem li in CheckBoxList1.Items){
            li.Attributes["title"] = "my title";
        }
}
```

Comment: Yup, already tried that, but the title attribute just gets set on the span and not the input.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Ed, please see my next solution below. This will work albeit a bit more tedious in your markup.

Comment: Another solution, especially if you want to have a reusable 508 compliant control is to write your own custom control. I didn't have code to offer before, but I found an example here that should get you off to a good start - http://www.jijeesh.8m.com/Articles/CustomCheckBoxList.html

Comment: Another good link with a custom CheckBoxList control - http://surinder.computing-studio.com/post/2011/08/10/ASPNET-CheckBoxList-Control-With-Value-Attribute.aspx

Comment: please don't rely on the title attribute. Being somebody who evaluates sites for compliance, using a title usually automatically fails the item in question.